# C++ arrays and System::Single?

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I'm relatively new to C++, and I'm trying to take an array within a class, and set it equal to a passed in array.

```
public ref class Example {
    array<float> ^ myarray1 = gcnew array<float>(3);
public:
    Example(float^ myarray2) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<3) {
            myarray[i] = myarray2[i];
            i += 1;
        }
}
```

In the main function, the constructor is called as follows:

```
float myarray2[] = {1,2,3};
Example ^example1 = gcnew Example(*myarray2)
```

The errors I get is are as follows:

1. System::Single' has no default indexed property (class indexer)
2. expression must have pointer-to-object or handle-to-C++/CLI-array
       type

Both of these errors are identified as happening where I am saying myarray[i] = myarray2[i].

I would greatly appreciate any help with solving this problem. I can't see where or how System::Single is getting pulled in as an error message. And, before it is suggested, I know I can get to work with setting myarray2 as a array float like myarray1, but I want it to work passing in myarray2 as float^ myarray2.

Comment: C++/CLI not C++. If C++/CLI better use managed object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you're new to C++, let me point out that you're not writing classic C++ there. You're writing [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is a set of language extensions to C++ designed to interoperate with the CLI (.NET Framework). Because of this, the type `float` in your code is an alias for the type [`System::Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx) of the framework.

Regarding the indexer issue, the error messages pretty much spell out the cases in which you would be allowed to use an indexer:

- > System::Single' has no default indexed property (class indexer)

  You could use an indexer if the type had a defined indexed property. `System::Single`, also known as `float`, doesn't happen to have one.
- > expression must have pointer-to-object type

  You could use the indexer if the type was a non-`void` pointer type. You'd have to declare it like this:

  ```
  Example(float* myarray2) {
  ```

  In this case, `myarray2[i]` is equivalent to the expression `*(myarray2 + i)`.
- > or handle-to-C++/CLI-array type

  You could use the indexer if the type was a handle (`^`) to a C++/CLI `array` type. As you already know, you'd have to declare it like this:

  ```
  Example(array<float> ^ myarray2) {
  ```

The bottom line is that, although you can treat a `float*` (pointer to `float`) like a C-style array of `float` (as a result of the rules of C and C++ about arrays and pointer arithmetic), these things simply do not apply to the `float^` (handle to `float`) type (which is C++/CLI-specific).

Answer (score 2):

```
   Example(float^ myarray2)
```

That does not mean what you think it does.  You are used to C language behavior, a float[] can automatically decay to a float* to the first element of the array.  Somewhat unfortunately also carried forward into C++.

But not into C++/CLI, it is fundamentally *unverifiable* code.  And responsible for a very large number of bugs and security problems.  One core problem is that your constructor has no idea how many elements are stored in the array.  You hard-coded "3" but if the caller passes an array that's smaller then Very Bad Things happen.

What it *actually* means is "reference to a boxed copy of a System::Single".  The compiler tries to make sense of that, inevitably it starts to get *very* confused what you try to do next.  Like using the [] operator, that requires the type to have an indexer.  A float doesn't have one.

You need either:

```
Example(array<float>^ myarray2)
```

Which is safe and verifiable, you can't index the array out of bounds.  And you don't have to hard-code "3" anymore, you can simply use myarray2->Length instead.  And you don't (usually) have the copy the array anymore, simply assign myarray1.  You'd call the constructor by passing `gcnew array<float> { 1, 2, 3 }`.

Or:

```
Example(float* myarray2)
```

Which works just like the way it does in C and C++.  And required if you want to call the constructor with that float[].  Not verifiable, you need that magic "3".  Do consider adding an extra argument to pass the array length.